# How to invovle the clang error:linker command failed in SMFL configuration in macbook

Tags: c++

Rencently, i am studying SMFL. i have downloaded SMFL liberaries in SMFL official cite, and follow the next teaching process to configuration

cite:https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-osx.php#installing-sfml,

Process:

[image: Process]

but it still not work in vscode,and the error like this:

[image: Error]

what made me confuesd is the test.cpp worked in command line when i used command g++ to compile and link.
The test.cpp in following:

```
#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

int main()
{
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(320,480),"This Game");
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        Event e;
        while(window.pollEvent(e))
        {
            if(e.type == Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        window.clear(Color::White);
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: Are you importing the libraries in vscode?

Comment: How should I import the library in vscode. I have followed the steps of the process picture to copy the folder to the default path